# How to choose the right initial fitting parameters for I'm guessing a double exponential decay?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I'm stuck with failure tentative in trying to guess the initial fitting parameters to give to scipy.optimize.curve_fit, in order to fit my data (which has logarithmic y-axis). I'm guessing it's a double exponential fitting due to the double decay (I'll may be wrong though). The code and the produced graph are below. [image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def double_exponential(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a*np.exp(-c*(x-b))+d

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.array([7.13793103, 21.4137931, 35.68965517, 49.96551724, 64.24137931, 78.51724138, 92.79310345, 107.06896552, 121.34482759, 135.62068966, 149.89655172, 164.17241379, 178.44827586, 192.72413793, 207.00000000, 221.27586207, 235.55172414, 249.82758621, 264.10344828, 278.37931034, 292.65517241, 306.93103448, 321.20689655, 335.48275862, 349.75862069, 364.03448276, 378.31034483, 392.5862069, 406.86206897, 421.13793103])
y = np.array([169954, 20599, 7309, 3989, 2263, 1569, 1134, 1017, 788, 806, 693, 528, 502, 431, 445, 367, 277, 267, 255, 189, 171, 109, 76, 36, 18, 9, 4, 3, 2, 1])
y_pruned = np.where(y < 1, 1, y)
p0 = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)  # only an example (I've tried other values without success)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(double_exponential, x, np.log(y_pruned), p0=p0)

ax.plot(x, double_exponential(x, *popt), 'g--')
ax.plot(x, np.log(y_pruned), 'ro')

ax.set_yscale('log')  # I need to have the y-axis logarithmic
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but it does not seem to me to be a double exponential. In the log-plot, it seems a fourth-order polynomial, and if you try, it fits quite well:

[image]

I just fitted `x and np.log(y)` using the function:

```
def f(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a*x**3 +b*x**2 + c*x + d
```

the result of the fit is:

```
a:  -4.933e-07 +/- 4.82e-08   (-9.8%)  initial:1
b:  0.0003011 +/- 3.14e-05   (10.4%)  initial:1
c:  -0.06804 +/- 0.00579   (-8.5%)  initial:1
d:  11.406  +/- 0.286      (2.5%)  initial:1
```

If you really want to fit `x` and `y` and not `log(y)` it is a bit more tricky since the residual coming from the first few points are way bigger and the fit function ignores the small point on the right:

```
def f(x, a=-4.933e-07, b=0.0003011, c=-0.06804, d=11.406):
    return np.exp(a*x**3 +b*x**2 + c*x + d)
```

[image]

Of course, you can adjust this behavior weighing the points in the fit function, and it works, but it seems to me to be a bit overcomplicated with respect to just fitting the log of the data:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you're totaly right in the fourth-order polynomial fitting. Can you please explain me what are you meaning with a = -4.933e-07 +/- 4.82e-08   (-9.8%)  initial:1 (I can get that -4.933e-07 is popt[0] and initail:1 stands for the default guessing parameter of scipy.optimize.curve_fit, but the +/- 4.82e-08 what is it)?

Comment: I was lazy and since I don't like `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` much for testing, I used my own wrapper library to do the fits. You are right about popt[0], the second parameter is the standard error, the third is the relative error, the fourth is the initial parameter used in the fit. Standard error meaning `np.sqrt(popt[1][0,0])`.